# How to pass varying number of arguments from tuple to string format in python?

Tags: python, format, tuples

I am facing a difficulty in passing varying number of arguments from tuple to string format.
Sometimes my tuple consists of only one value, but sometimes up to 10 values.
If I want to print all of the values in print statement how do I do that?
I have tried:

```
tup = ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
print('List consists of: {}'.format(*tup))
```

but it prints out only the first value. Unfortunately, each time I have varying number of arguments to print.

Comment: Join them in the case of multiple strings? `.format(', '.join(tup))`

Comment: thank you, that worked perfect for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The special syntax `*args` (`*mystrings` in our case) in function definitions in python is used to pass a **variable number of arguments** to a function. It is used to pass a **non-keyworded, variable-length argument list**.

The nice thing here that they are passed as a `tuple` by python which make this a
Classic and strait forward approach. see this approach in the `code snippet` bellow:

```
def foo(*mystrings): ## which ofen used as *args
    for string in mystrings:
    print(string)    ## Or do what ever you want.
```

Now call it:

```
tup = ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
foo(tup)
```

If you want just to construct a string from the `tuple` you can use `join()` method to do the job:

```
strt=' '.join(tup)
```

**str.join(iterable)**

Return a string which is the concatenation of the strings in iterable. A TypeError will be raised if there are any non-string values in iterable, including bytes objects. The separator between elements is the string providing this method.

Comment: thank you, `' '.join(tup)` solution worked perfectly for me

Comment: welcome. if find it useful please vote up my answer and choose it by pushing on the v left side the answer.
the most frustrating thing that this site allows **weired** people to down vote the answer without any usefl explination. this shall be blocked by the community.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the * so you are not unpacking the tuple:

```
tup = ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
print('List consists of: {}'.format(tup))
```

Output:

```
List consists of: ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to avoid having brackets and quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `.format()` or `.join()` in this case. Just pass `*tup` as agument to the print function:

```
>>> tup = ('h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'world')
>>> print(*tup)
h e l l o world
```

It works for number's too;

```
tup = (1, 2 ,3)

print('List consists of:', *tup)
```

```
[OUTPUT]: List consists of: 1 2 3
```

And you can add separators if you want;

```
print('List consists of:', *tup, sep=', ')
```

```
[OUTPUT]: List consists of: 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Hi and thank you, this solution would have worked if I had decimals, but in my case I had strings inside tuple.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show it works with strings.